# Perform same set of data manipulations on all tables in an SQLite database

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have an SQLite database with tables having a poor schema. Basically, there is no index column which acts like a primary key, so I wish to add a column that has an auto incremental value , to the existing set of rows.
For achieving the above I applied the following SQL commands to a particular table say `table_orig`. I create a new table named `table1` and insert rows from `table_orig` into it.

```
create table table1(id integer primary key autoincrement, col1 varchar, col2 varchar, col3 float, col4 float, col5 float, col6 float, col7 float);

insert into table1(col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6, col7) select col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6, col7 from table_orig;

drop table table_orig;

alter table table1 rename to table_orig;
```

Now, there are 100 tables in my database and I wish to apply these commands to each of them. How do I automate this, as I don't want to manually do it for each of them?

Any help will be appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: SQLite does not support dynamic SQL, so do a loop in the programming language that you prefer on all the tables of the db.

Comment: Unless it's a `WITHOUT ROWID` table (with a mandatory primary key), all SQLite tables have a primary key that is an auto generated integer if not given explicitly. You don't have to do anything special. See https://sqlite.org/rowidtable.html

Comment: https://sqlite.org/autoinc.html is also mandatory reading.